# How to make notification bar and bottom bar in browser transparent for website in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to make this nots bar and bottom bar of broswer transparent for both android and iOS so that whatever color of my website page is, that color is reflected in them.

I already added this code to make nots bar transparent but i guess its only for android:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ),
);
```